# What is the best place to add load new data to Store? ngrx/store

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am wondering what is the best place to load new data to ngrx/store during accessing the product details page in Spartacus store. I was trying to do it by adding resolver for this path, but it seems not work.
Please, advice where this type of actions should be callled.

Comment: I don't think it's really spartacus-related question. Please read more about ngrx itself: https://ngrx.io/docs. Plus maybe read about ngrx good practices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question properly but I think you are looking for these links

Sample Code --> https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/blob/develop/projects/core/src/user/facade/user-order.service.ts

Connecting to other systems --> https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/